# Changing the color of git branch output?

Tags: bash, git, colors, prompt

In my .bash_profile I have a `parse_git_branch` function from the internet, and a PS1 to color some of my output.

If possible, I would like to make my git branch name colored red, instead of white.

I tired changing a few variables, but with no luck. I would like `(master)` to be red, if possible.

[image]

Comment: OK; I gave you one free fish. Now it’s time for you to [learn to fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). P.S. Please post text as text rather than screenshots.

Comment: @G-Man I think I found the solution, but I don't have my laptop with me at the moment to try it. I think by changing \w\[033[m]\ to \w\[033[31m]\ would give the desired output. I thought I had tried something like that and it didn't work, but I don't remember. I tried a few things before making a question.

Comment: That sounds right.

Comment: @G-Man that did the trick. Thanks for the link you shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the git branch to print out in red by changing

```
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[93m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] \n$ "
```

to

```
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[93m\]\w\[\033[31m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] \n$ "
```

To highlight the specific change was using `[31m\]\$(parse_git_branch)` instead of `[m\]\$(parse_git_branch)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use color codes for this.

```
PS1='\e[31TextInRed\e[0m'
```

Where `\e[31` will render everything on the terminal in red color, 31 being the color code for red and `\e[0m` resets the color back to normal so that your terminal isn't messed up(i.e all the text would be colored in red).

Read more about color codes [here](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)